# Javascript - binding of `this` in non-strict mode

Tags: javascript, this

In the following learners piece of code, call to `foo()` below was expected to return `"bar1"` based on the following understanding that in non-strict mode, the `this` keyword binds to global based on the `default binding` rule and `undefined` in strict mode.

```
function foo(){
  console.log(this.bar);
}
var bar = 'bar1';
var o1 = {bar: 'bar2', foo: foo};
var o2 = {bar: 'bar3', foo: foo};

foo();       // expect 'bar1' - default binding
o1.foo();    // expect 'bar2' - implicit binding
o2.foo();    // expect 'bar3' - implicit binding
```

However the on calling `foo()` I'm getting `undefined` in console. `o1.foo()` and `o2.foo()` behaves as expected based on `implicit binding`. It seems to me that the binding is working as expected, but the bar variable is never stuck on to global.

I ran the script in node 6

```
> node script.js
undefined
bar2
bar3
```

Note:- in browser it gives the expected output.

Comment: Your `var bar` is not a global variable, but one in the module's implicit scope. Create it without `var` by explicit assignment, or as `global.bar = 'bar1';`

Comment: @Rayon - I don't think that is true - there is global obj in node

Comment: @Bergi – I was not aware of that.. Just executed that code in `cmd` and realized that... Deleted my comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Node modules run in their own closure, so `var bar` is actually creating a local variable, not a global one.

Node modules are essentially wrapped like this, so they don't run in the global scope.

```
function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { /*your code here*/
}
```

If you were to do `bar = 'bar1';` without the `var`, or `global.bar = 'bar1';` you would create a global variable, and you would get your expected output. Don't actually do that in production though, it pollutes the global space.

Comment: makes sense. One follow-up question. Running the code (same as in OP) in strict mode `"using strict"` gives `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined`

Comment: @user3206440 Yes, the implicit `this` is `undefined` in strict mode, and trying to access a property of undefined throws a `TypeError`.